# github scheduled cron job not triggering every 5 minutes

Tags: cron, github-actions, schedule

```
name: Scheduled Job

on:
  schedule:
    - cron: "*/5 * * * *" # Runs every 5 minutes
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened]
    branches:
     - main
  workflow_dispatch: {}

jobs:
  scheduled-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Print Current Time
        run: echo "The current time is $(date)
```

The above github actions workflow YAML is not triggering for every 5 minutes when I pushed the feature branch and raise a PR

Please guide me the reason why the CRON job is not triggered?

Answer (score 3):

> not triggering for every 5 minutes when I pushed the feature branch and raise a PR

It does not trigger for a feature branch because the documentation clearly states this:

> Scheduled workflows run on the latest commit on the default or base branch. The shortest interval you can run scheduled workflows is once every 5 minutes.

This part should for sure trigger for a push to the `main` branch though:

```
  push:
    branches:
      - main
```

and that might be redundant with the whole cron schedule. I'm not sure if a scheduled workflow will trigger for commits that have already been verified on push.

Pull request against the `main` branch should also automatically trigger without the whole cron part:

```
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened]
    branches:
     - main
```

If none of these trigger, first make sure your default branch really is `main` and and not `master`. `main` is the new default at GH, but your local git installation might still use `master`.

See the documentation for more: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#schedule